# c# call child method from parent list

Tags: c#, parent-child

I have the following problem:
I have a list of UserControls for a wizard application and need to call a child method

```
List<UserControl> steps = new List<UserControl>();
steps.Add(new Step1());
steps.Add(new Step2());
steps.Add(new Step3());
steps.Add(new Step4());
```

All have StopTimeOut() method. How can I call: `steps[0].StopTimeOut();` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Should be as easy as written in the question itself: `steps[0].StopTimeOut();`. Do you get a compile time error if you try using that? Is that method `public`, `private`, `internal` or `protected`?

Comment: ... what's wrong with what you wrote (`steps[0].StopTimeOut();`) ?

Comment: He has to cast first ( ((Step)steps[0]).StopTimeOut(); ) - or use a List<Step>.

Comment: Ah yeah, good point. Since he was using a generic I didn't even notice it wasn't a List<Step>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you already did it:

```
steps[0].StopTimeOut();
```

Just declare in base class of all Step classes `StopTimeOut` method as `protected` or `public`

Example:

```
public Step : UserControl {
    ....
    public virtual void StopTimeOut() {
         //BASE IMPLEMENTATION
    }
}

public Step1 : Step {
    public override void StopTimeOut() {
         //CHILD IMPLEMENTATION
    }
}

public Step2 : Step {
    public override void StopTimeOut() {
         //CHILD IMPLEMENTATION
    }
}
..
```

and in code:

```
List<Step> steps = new List<Step>();
steps.Add(new Step1());
steps.Add(new Step2());
..
```

Comment: Each Step object has a different implementation. I have to call the method of the child and not the interface.

Comment: @MiguelCadaviz: so make it `virtual` in base, and override it in every child that has its own implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You should put the method in a common base class (eg, `StepControl`) and make all four controls inherit from it.

You can then make a `List<StepControl>` and call the function directly.